# Cannot read properties of undefined while testing if undefined (but it is defined)?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following chunk of Typescript code in a function, with `variableInQuestion = 0` being defined outside of the function:

```
console.log(this.variableInQuestion);
this.arrayOfObjects.each(function(thing) {
    if (this.variableInQuestion !== undefined && thing.property == this.variableInQuestion) {
        ...
    }
});
```

The problem is that the console.log line prints out exactly what I would expect (the default value of 0), but I get an error for the third line saying `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'variableInQuestion') at [[[location of the first variableInQuestion in the third line]]]`.  I don't understand why it's giving me a "cannot read properties of undefined" error while I am testing to see if it's undefined.

EDIT: the `.each` thing is specific to the array of objects in question; that's not the issue.  If I run the following...

```
console.log(this.variableInQuestion);
this.arrayOfObjects.each(function(thing) {
    if (0 !== undefined && thing.property == 0) {
        ...
    }
});
```

It works exactly as I'd expect.

Comment: Where does `.each()` come from? The Typescript/JavaScript array iteration method is called "forEach", not "each".

Comment: can you post the actual code? it is hard to understand with your example

Comment: In any case the error is that `this` is `undefined`, and that's because there's no default `this` binding in an iterative method like "forEach". If you use an `=>` function, you'll get the `this` binding from the enclosing context.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 1):

The way to address this problem is as follows:

```
variableInQuestion = 0;

myFunction() {
    let placeholder = this.variableInQuestion;
    this.arrayOfObjects.each(function(thing) {
        if (placeholder !== undefined && thing.property == placeholder) {
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

Special thanks to Pointy for identifying the problem!

Answer (score 0):

If you `console.log` your data, you'll see

```
class X {
    variableInQuestion = 123;
    arrayOfObjects = [1, 2, 3];

    example() {
        console.log(this.variableInQuestion);
        this.arrayOfObjects.forEach(function (thing) {
            console.log({
                this: this,
                thing: thing,
            })
        })
    }
}

new X().example()
// 123
// { "this": undefined, thing: 1 }
// { "this": undefined, thing: 2 }
// { "this": undefined, thing: 3 }
```

because `forEach` doesn't keep `this` value.

Either use lambda

```
this.arrayOfObjects.forEach((thing) => { console.log(this) })
```

, keep `this` value

```
let that = this;
this.arrayOfObjects.forEach((thing) => { console.log(that) })
```

, or provide `thisArg` into `forEach` (dunno about `.each` but `Array.prototype.forEach supports that`)

```
this.arrayOfObjects.forEach(function(thing){ console.log(this) }, this)
```